# login facebook android notworking

Tags: java, android, facebook

when install my app from eclipse on real device it works ok with login to face book sample app

but when exporting it to apk and install it manually to my mobile 
when hit login then hit ok about facebook permission then i get back again to login screen

i don't know why it not working with apk version

my code :

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
 loginface.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Call logout twitter function




 // start Facebook Login
    Session.openActiveSession(LoginActivity.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

      // callback when session changes state
      @Override
      public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {

          // make request to the /me API
          Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            // callback after Graph API response with user object
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
              if (user != null) {
                TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
                welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });

        }
    });

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

XML file:

```
     <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_fblogin"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 This works for me.....
```

`   Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

```
            // callback when session changes state

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {

                Request.newMeRequest(session, new            Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {




                    }

                }).executeAsync();

            }

        });`
```